# How does hot air remove guests from cyclodextrin?

Tags: organic-chemistry, dipole

Cyclodextrin, as I know, has a hydrophobic cavity. Therefore, it would absorb hydrophobic organic compounds. But the organic compound can also be removed with hot air since the interaction between the organic compound and the cavity is an induced dipole attraction. How much heat would be enough to break the attraction and how would it break the attraction?